# SQL:calculate start and end date( from ending until starting)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management System.
I have got this table here:

[image]

And I would like to calculate(minus) from next row 'started' with the previous 'ended'. Like in the picture marked.

```
2016-01-07 02:24:37.357 - 2016-01-07 02:24:25.170 = 0,000138889


started                   ended
2016-01-04 22:40:35.930   2016-01-05 02:01:36.500
2016-01-06 23:32:27.163   2016-01-07 02:24:25.170
2016-01-07 02:24:37.357   2016-01-07 02:57:04.010
2016-01-07 03:03:12.300   2016-01-07 22:41:55.473
2016-01-07 22:42:05.043   2016-01-07 22:55:07.947
2016-01-07 22:55:16.570   2016-01-08 00:23:08.263
2016-01-08 00:34:35.297   2016-01-08 05:32:54.967
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column data types?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: also please take time to paste some sample data,instead of image

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag` to get the previous row's ended column and use it for subtraction.

```
select *, 
datediff(second,lag(ended) over(partition by status order by started),started) as diff_column
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or newer, for this one you can use LEAD and LAG functions, otherwise you will need to embed this logic around a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATEDIFF(lag(ended),lead(started)) from tablename
```